# How do you access the applications display name in windows phone 8.1 (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I need to access the display name field stored in the Package.appxmanifest. I am developing in Xamarin Forms and am trying to access this from the windows phone 8.1 project through dependency injection.

To make it a little bit more clear this is the field I am trying to retrieve:

[image: Package.appxmanifest]

When I try accessing information from the Package.Current I don't see any options for the display name. I get the following options (none of these are the correct one):

[image: Package.Current.Id]

Does anyone have any ideas how I can access this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't, have a look at this page in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Package#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_DisplayName). It has this remark;

> This property is only supported for Windows Store app. If you call
>   this property on an instance of a package that was created by any
>   mechanism other than Package.Current, this property returns an empty
>   string ("").

I'm not sure if the `Package.appxmanifest` file is still in the app that is installed on the device, if so, you could try to read it manually and extract it from there.

Comment: What exactly defines a windows store app? because the app could be uploaded to the windows store and be a windows store app...

Comment: A Windows Store App in that time was a desktop app. At the time of Windows 8 there was a Windows Store and Windows Phone Store. This all was before UWP.